# one login session for multi scripts installed on website

Tags: php, session, authentication

I want to build a website and install more than one php scripts like wordpress, vbulletin forum, upload center....etc . And I will create a simple php code so I can combine all members database of the scripts installed to be one time registration .
My question is how can make all login for these script to be one time login , if I login one forum it will be directly loginned to upload center & wordpress and others.
 i will explain more hope you get my idea: let's say that i have one page name (login.php) this page is for user login, after the user login success the user be automatically loginned to all other scripts installed in the site.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use login via Social Networks (the most simple case). Most CMS have plugins to login via Social Networks. If you want support universal login via email/password AND social networks I guess you should write your own Login Service (or find one) and write plugins for those websites which will use that service

Comment: Iam not sure if you understand what i mean but i don't think that logining from social network will be the solution, i will explain more hope you get my idea: let's say that i have one page name (login.php) this page is for user login, after the user login success the user be loginned in all other scripts installed in the site.

Comment: @user2873860 you should write your own Login Service that all scripts should use to get user data